# How to fold and static_assert all parameters?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, static-assert, fold-expression

The following doesn't compile:

```
  template<typename... Args>
  void check_format(Args&&... args)
  {
      static_assert((true && std::is_fundamental<decltype(args)>::value)...);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt looks like a mix between a unary and a binary fold expression. The correct forms of the expression as either unary or binary folds are

```
static_assert((... && std::is_fundamental<decltype(args)>::value));         // unary
static_assert((true && ... && std::is_fundamental<decltype(args)>::value)); // binary
```

The unary form works because an empty sequence is implicitly equivalent to `true`.

By the way, `decltype(args)` is always gonna be a reference type, either lvalue or rvalue. You probably want to `std::remove_reference_t` from those types. And you may as well use `std::remove_reference_t<Args>` for ease of writing.

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
static_assert((std::is_fundamental_v<Args> && ...));
```

Longer example on godbolt: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9yNf15

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Args>
constexpr bool check_format(Args&&... args)
{
    return (std::is_fundamental_v<Args> && ...);
}

int main() {
    static_assert(check_format(1, 2, 3));
    static_assert(check_format(nullptr));
    static_assert(!check_format("a"));
    static_assert(check_format());
    struct Foo {};
    static_assert(!check_format(Foo{}));
}
```